# como manejar las rutas en python con flask

Tags: python, flask

estoy tratando de aprender python y estoy creando un sencillo crud, estoy tratando de separar las funciones de los decoradores, algo así

```
from functions.demo import funcion_de_prueba

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
   funcion_de_prueba(request.json)
```

en la funcion que guardo en otro archivo no tengo nada mas que esto

```
def Registrar_usuario(data):
   print(data)
   return data
```

la función parece ejecutarse por que me muestra los datos por consola, pero no retorna nada a pesar que este declarado el return, aclaro que ya busque posibles soluciones pero y se resolvían simplemente declarando un return para que la consulta POST tenga un valor de vuelta pero aquí no retorna el data y la consola me devuelve esto

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None 
or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: Las rutas en Flask, tienen que devolver siempre algo y en tu caso devuelves None, algo que a Flask no le gusta, prueba con añadir `return 'OK'` en la función de `index`

Comment: lo aclare en la pregunta, lo que intento yo es manejar solamente el endpoint con una funcion traida de otro archivo, declarar un return debajo del decorador es lo que no quiero, quiero que la misma funcion sea la que maneje todo